# What is the maximum length of an un-encrypted password using the ASP.Net Membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, asp.net-membership

I have a production site using the `Encrypted` style password storage from the SQL Membership Provider and for particularly long passwords we're getting the exception:

> The password is too long: It must not exceed 128 chars after encrypting. Parameter name `newPassword`.

This is being thrown from `MembershipUser.ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)`, although the stack may go a little deeper.

What maximum length do I need to limit my users to so that we don't see this error if they provide a password of that length?

I realise that we should really have been using `Hashed` which should result in a more consistent result, but as a short term fix before we convert all the existing passwords I'd like to reduce the maximum number of characters a user can enter to keep the encrypted length under this limit.

Comment: Arn't the passwords hashed => same lenght for all?

Comment: I believe that the `Encrypted` style adds a salt and then encrypts the password so that it can potentially be retrieved, rather than just storing the hash (please let's not discuss the validity of this at this point - I'm well aware that really we should be using `Hashed`).

Comment: IMO no discussion needed: Use hashing as it solves your problem AND should be used anyway. Because I think you can't "really solve" the problem, as for encryption there is possibly no "one max. value" as one shorter string encrypted could be longer than a longer one...

Comment: Yes, I fear you are right... New to this particular project however and I'm not entirely sure of the implications of changing it as there are number of other dependencies on the web.config

Comment: Bear in mind though that sadly this is production system, so has a number of existing encrypted passwords in place - changing the type now would require an additional exercise in decrypting, and re-hashing all those passwords as well :(

Comment: i would say its non-deterministic - it all depends on what chars are in the password and what asp.net uses to encrypt them.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.changepassword(v=vs.110).aspx), it is exactly 128 chars in the database. It also can vary with the encryption strategy and what is in the string.